# How can I redirect to current page after a successful Facebook login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am implementing a Facebook login in my Rails 3 application.  I have gotten it to work but it redirects to the "Site URL" I specified in my Facebook application.  I would like it to redirect to the page from which the user has logged in.  For instance if they login from http://www.site.com/userprofile then it should stay on that page after login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons Facebook will only redirect back to a pre-registered URL, you cannot change it dynamically.  You have to receive the callback at this pre-definded URL and then redirect the user where you want afterwards.

Alternately, you can run them through the Facebook login in a popup and at the end have the popup just tell the `window.opener` to reload and then close itself.  Just feed it JavaScript instead in the response.

Comment: I suppose I want to use this state parameter or some other method.  Actually I want to use Ajax so that seems like it will bypass this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a good way to implement it. State parameter is used to avoid CSRF. The document says "A unique string used to maintain application state between the request and callback. When Facebook redirects the user back to your redirect_uri, this parameter's value will be included in the response. You should use this to protect against Cross-Site Request Forgery." If I were you, I would store the current url in a session data and when user gets redirected to the page that is defined in "Site URL," check the session data that you stored the url earlier and redirect him to it.